# How to get item from laravel eloquent collection by conditions?

Tags: laravel, collections, eloquent

I use **laravel eloquent** to get files of post that give me a collection
but I want an **item from that collection by condition**.
For example from that collection I want an item that `type = 'product'`.

I am using foreach and check every item that have my condition and return it, but isn't any better way?

I tested collection method like contain but it return `null`.

Files item have type filed that value is 'product' or 'blog'.

My code:

```
$post= Post::where('slug' , $slug)->first();

$cover = $post->files->contains(['type' , '=' , 'product']);
```

Comment: Use `filter` method. It's in the documentation.

Comment: Is `$post->files` a relationship?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the collection `filter` method.

```php
$cover = $post->files->filter(function($file) {
    // show only the items that match this condition
    return collect(['product', 'blog'])->contains($file->type);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The filter method filters the collection using the given callback, keeping only those items that pass a given truth test:

```
$filtered = $post->files->filter(function ($value, $key) {
    return $value->type == 'product';
});

$filtered->all();
```

[Collections - filter()](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#method-filter)